# Как работает эта формула?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Начиная с ДВССЫЛ перестал понимать. Особенно сложно с фигурными скобками и знаком &.

```
=ТРАНСП(ДВССЫЛ("'ЛИСТ_1'!"&ArrayFormula({АДРЕС(17;3)&":"&АДРЕС(21;СЧЁТЗ('ЛИСТ_1'!17:17)+2)})))
```

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на Таблицу с примером данных.

Comment: Фигурные скобки - создают массив. Амперсанд - оператор строковой конкатенации.

Answer (score 0):

Формула выводит данные из диапазона на листе `ЛИСТ_1`. Где адрес диапазона строится по определенным условиям.

Никакой нужды в скобках и `ARRAYFORMULA` нет. Кто-то перестарался, или неумело пытался запутать.

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(
  "'ЛИСТ_1'!"&
  ADDRESS(17,3)&
  ":"&
  ADDRESS(21,COUNTA('ЛИСТ_1'!17:17)+2)
))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обычно, когда запутались, формулу решают "луковым" или "капустным" методом. Это когда начинают разбирать формулу от большего к меньшему, как будто снимают листья капусты.

Получает адрес диапазона в виде строки для `INDIRECT`

```
="'ЛИСТ_1'!"&
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    {ADDRESS(17,3)&":"&ADDRESS(21,COUNTA('ЛИСТ_1'!17:17)+2)}
  )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкатенирует значения в строку-диапазон

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({ADDRESS(17,3)&":"&ADDRESS(21,COUNTA('ЛИСТ_1'!17:17)+2)})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получает адрес по координатам: 21 строка и колонка, номер которой равен количеству значений в строке 17 плюс 2.

```
=ADDRESS(21,COUNTA('ЛИСТ_1'!17:17)+2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Фигурные скобки не нужны. Они определяют массив констант и не могут содержать внутри себя ссылки.

*АДРЕС* - текстовая функция, медленная. *ДВССЫЛ* - медленная и, мало того, что работает с текстами, - она еще и пересчитывается когда надо и не надо (летучая). *СЧЕТЗ* не стоит применять для всей строки (считает весь диапазон, а не только ограниченный данными). Вместо нее - `СЧЁТЕСЛИ(Лист_1!17:17;"?*")` (если там числа - "<>")

Диапазон можно создать функциями полегче:

```
ИНДЕКС(Лист_1!C:C;17):ИНДЕКС(Лист_1!$1:$1000;21;СЧЁТЕСЛИ(Лист_1!17:17;"<>")+2)
```

Для транспонирования диапазона формулу следует вводить, как формулу массива (В Excel функция `ТРАНСП` - массивная, возможно, в *Google* - таблицах не так...)